# vue-i18n-next: Variables not working when using the composition api in vue 3.2 setup script

Tags: vue.js, vuejs3, vue-i18n

In a vue 3.2 project I'm working with `vue-i18n-next` v9, the `composition api` and the `<script setup>` approach.

I'm trying to create a translated message with some variables indicated by `{}'s`. For example

```
export default {
    conclusion: `After reviewing the above invoices, it was found that there is currently a difference of about {total_difference} in your {advantage_type} on the whole of these invoices.`
}
```

My vue component looks like this:

```
<script setup>
    import { ref } from 'vue';
    import { useI18n } from 'vue-i18n';
    import { getHumanPrice } from '@/utils/helpers';

    const { t } = useI18n();

    const total_difference = ref(2000);

    const conclusion = computed(() => {
        return t('conclusion', 1, {
            total_difference: total_difference.value
            advantage_type: total_difference.value >= 0 ? t('advantage', 1).toLowerCase() : t('disadvantage', 1).toLowerCase(),
        });
    });
</script>
```

The result is a string without the variable parts `After reviewing the above invoices, it was found that there is currently a difference of about in your on the whole of these invoices.`

Previously, when using vue-i18n-next package with the options api in vue 2, there was no problem and the string was correctly formed with the variables. The code looked like this:

```
<script>
    export default: {
        data() {
            return {
                total_difference: 2000,
            }
        },
        computed: {
            conclusion() {
                return this.$tc('conclusion', 1, {
                    total_difference: this.$filters.getHumanPrice(this.total_difference, 2),
                    advantage_type: this.total_difference >= 0 ? t('advantage', 1).toLowerCase() : t('disadvantage', 1).toLowerCase(),
                });
            },
        }
    }
</script>
```

The output was `After reviewing the above invoices, it was found that there is currently a difference of about $2500,00 in your advantage on the whole of these invoices.`

Any idea what has been changed or what I could be doing wrong with the composition api approach?

Comment: It's unknown what's not working. "Previously I could use this code with the options api and $tc without any problem" - which code exactly? Are Vue and i18n versions the same?

Comment: @EstusFlask I have reworked the question. I hope it's clearer now. My Vue version is 3.2.30, vue-i18n is version 9.2.0-beta.14

Comment: You changed `$tc` to `t` and should expect that there will be differences in use.

Answer (score 0):

`$tc` provides a translation with pluralization, a drop-in replacement for it would be `tc`:

```
tc('conclusion', 1, { ... })
```

`t` is general translation function, although it allows to use pluralization, it cannot accept an object for named interpolation as an argument because there may be [other options](https://vue-i18n.intlify.dev/api/general.html#translateoptions), in this case it should be:

```
t('conclusion', 1, { named: { ... } })
```